# How do you ignore an item when destructuring an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I'm self-answering this because I didn't come across a question or answer that discussed ignoring a destructured array element while searching.

Is there a way to ignore an element of a array when destructuring?  The closest thing that I can think of is how in Go you can use the `_` symbol to drop an argument.

I'm using ESLint and I'd like to be able to avoid unused variable warnings without having to explicitly turn off the warning.  I also don't like the scope leak even though it is rather minimal.

For example:

```js
const arr = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["fizz", "buzz"],
  ["hello", "world"]
];

// I don't actually want 'a' to be available in the scope
arr.forEach(([a, b]) => console.log(`a: ${a} | b: ${b}`));

// _ is still defined and equates to 'a' above
arr.forEach(([_, b]) => console.log(`'a': ${_} | b: ${b}`));
```

Comment: If you can self answer it immediately after you ask it, it is not much of a question is it? It seems more like a documentation than a question. I am not sure if SO supports/allows that.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ it could help others, though

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ [Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Sacha [Can I answer my own question? - Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Andreas How did I miss that?  I typed that exact title and still didn't see it.  I could have sworn I sorted by relevance as well.

Comment: Use google (or any other search provider) for searching. The built-in search isn't that good... :(

Comment: And another question were SOs search system failed. I mean both this question and the dupe got ignore / destructuring / array / [javascript] in their title ...

Answer (score 18):

You can ignore an element by simply not providing a variable for the value to be assigned to and just putting the comma as though you had.  See [MDN: Destructuring assignment#Ignoring some returned values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values).

For example:

```js
const arr = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["fizz", "buzz"],
  ["hello", "world"]
];

// Just use ','
arr.forEach(([, b]) => {
  // No variable is populated with the first element
  console.log(typeof(a));
  console.log(typeof(b));
  console.log(`b: ${b}`);
});
```